# SSMS - Pivoting a column and changing the field names

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

Say I have the following table, Table1

```
SIMULATION  STATEMENT_LINE                  PERIOD  OUTPUT_YTDIncStmt
0           A_1_a_Gross_Written_Premium     2012Q2  1362419134
0           A_Net_Earned_Premium            2012Q2  0
0           A_1_Gross_Earned_Premium        2012Q2  1362419134
```

Is there any way I can pivot the STATEMENT_LINE column so instead of having all that A_1 and what not, I can make it look like so...

```
PERIOD    [Gross Written Premium]    [Net Earned Premium]    [Gross Earned Premium]
2012Q2          1362419134                    0                     1362419134
```

I would like to personally specify what the columns are going to be called and not just get rid of the "_" and the "A" or "1".

What's a good way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have an unknown number of `STATEMENT_LINE` values or will you just have 3?

Comment: I have a lot but I only need to choose about 6.  If I wanted all I would definitely be using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
SELECT [Period],
    [A_1_a_Gross_Written_Premium] AS [Gross Written Premium],
    [A_Net_Earned_Premium] AS [Net Earned Premium],
    [A_1_Gross_Earned_Premium] AS [Gross Earned Premium]
FROM
  (
   SELECT [STATEMENT_LINE], [PERIOD], [OUTPUT_YTDIncStmt]
   FROM Table1
   ) AS Source

PIVOT
  (
   MAX(OUTPUT_YTDIncStmt)
   FOR STATEMENT_LINE IN ([A_1_a_Gross_Written_Premium], [A_Net_Earned_Premium], [A_1_Gross_Earned_Premium])
  ) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: I'm so dumb...I did the same thing except that I put `'A_1_a_Gross_Written_Premium' AS [Gross Written Premium]` which was giving me the actual wording and not the numbers I needed lol.  Thanks!!